# Variance of linear density field $\sigma_{R}^{2}$ equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, statistics

The variance of the linear density field in cosmology $\sigma_{8}$ on 8Mpc, which is used to normalize the matter power spectrum is defined by the following equation:

$ \sigma_{8}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi^{2}}\int P_{linear}(k)\tilde{W}_{TH}^{2}(kR) k^{2}dk}, \quad \text{where}\quad R=8h^{-1}Mpc$.

My problem is that I can't find a way to derive this equation. Some lecture notes that I found claim that using the following equations:

1) The filtered density perturbation via convolution with a windows function W
$\delta_{R}(t,\bf{x})=\int \delta(t,\bf{x'})W(|\bf{x}-\bf{x'}|,R)d^{3}\bf{x'}$

2)The same expression in the Fourier Space $\delta_{R}(t,\bf{k})=\delta(t,\bf{k})\tilde{W}(kR)$, where $\tilde{W}(kR)=\int W(\bf{x},R)e^{-i\bf{k}\cdot \bf{x}}d^{3}\bf{x}$.

one can find, assuming the field is Gaussian, that

$\langle \delta_{R} \rangle =0$

$\sigma_{R}^{2}=\langle \delta_{R}^{2} \rangle=\frac{1}{2\pi^{2}}\int P(k)\tilde{W}^{2}(kR)k^{2}dk$.

**Could somebody guide me through the derivation of the last equation (the $\sigma_{R}^{2}$ one) using equations 1 and 2?**